# Concurrent execution of flows in mule

Tags: mule

I am looking for a pattern that can call, say for example, 2 different web services concurrently and not wait on them to complete their processing within a mule flow. Also if any of these 2 service calls fails then I want to continue and not fail.

I see that there is fork and join pattern provided within mule. My requirement differs in the sense that there is no join at the end and I also do not want to wait for the service calls to complete as my service calls are asynchronous in nature (an example would be call service1 to drop message into a queue AND call one way service2).

I have a high level example below where I want to fire Service1 & Service2 calls concurrently. The moment those 2 calls are initiated, I want the control to come back to main flow and start executing  and so on.

```
<flow>
 <async><Service1 call></async>
 <async><Service2 call></async>
 <Transformer>
 <Logger>
</flow>
```

Comment: Is both the service you are talking about is the last endpoint or these both service's result/output is necessary for next processing ?

Comment: Your current bigh level flow is the solution what you are expecting. Are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your described behavior is exactly what your flow example will do. The Service calls inside the  tags will be asynchronous, and the flow will continue with your Transformer without waiting for the Service calls to finish.

Comment: All of you are right. I had some doubts but apparently the flows invoked within <async> tags are pure asynchronous and they neither inherit the processing strategy nor the exception strategy of the triggering flow so the sequence within my flow outlined in my original question itself is the solution. Thanks all !!

Answer (score 0):

I guess to execute all your flows concurrently is to use `scatter-gather`
Inside `scatter-gather`you can use async block so that it doesn't affect if any flows fails.
The component is available from Mule 3.5 and here is the reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Scatter-Gather